# My site appears to be hacked

Tags: hacked, redirect

My site appears to be hacked. When I log on to the control panel http://www.elqanah-news.com/wp-login.php it gives redirects

Comment: , and when we talk to knownhost server administrators they reply to us "The site scripts and Databases were searched but there is no redirection rules to redirect http://www.elqanah-news.com/wp-admin/ to https://www.cnet.com/news/?tag=typo
Please check the wordpress dashboard settings also for redirects which can be accessed via http://www.elqanah-news.com/wp-login.php
Since the database and site scripts are not showing any such redirections then I suspect the Wordpress dashboard settings I mentioned above or the site's source code.

Comment: The source code should be checked with the help of a developer since coding is out of our scope".We want to inquire about the right solution

Comment: NB :
When I place a link "http://www.elqanah-news.com/wp-login.php".
It automatically converts it to "https://www.cnet.com/news/?tag=typ".

Comment: sorry, but how exactly do you expect from people that have no access to your sever and code be able to give you any meaningful help? If you can not debug the problem yourself, you should hire someone to do it

Answer (score 1):

Look at all of the 'related' links to the right of your question for help with a hacked site.

I would reinstall everything (WP, themes, plugins), check htaccess files (in all folders, not just the site root folder), change all site access passwords (ftp, host, email), check your local computer, look for unexpected files (in all folders, sort by date to help find anomalies).

If this is above your skillset, professional help may be required.

**Added**
For my own reference, I created a post about the things I do to fix a hacked site: http://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ .But the googles (and a search here) will give you much guidance on how to recover.